# Securing session and cookies

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I have few questions on securing sessions and cookies.

1. Session being a temporary file on server is deleted when browser is closed. I think it is not a easy task to breach a session. Moreover all the tutorials and documentations that teach of securing session actually speak of securing cookies so can I presume that when we use only sessions that expire on browser exit doesn't require any special session securing methods. If yes what we can use to secure session?
2. Cookies really need attention when using auto-login functions. We can enable strict mode for extra security which rejects uninitialized sessions. Aren't cookies in auto-login uninitialized sessions.
3. When using auto-login I think of securing cookie in a simple way, regenerating the session id and then hashing it with sha512, will this secure cookies?

Comment: Server side session is not necessarily a file. It is not deleted when the browser closes.

Comment: Regarding 3, that doesn't help anything, since the next time a user hits your site they will have a new session id, so any information about a previous session id is useless.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read: [The Fast Track to Safe and Secure PHP Sessions](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions).

   There are a few ways you can store session data:

   - In a file (PHP's default behavior)
   - In a database (many frameworks do this)
   - In memcached (what I do)
   - In the cookie itself (generally a bad idea)

   Unless you're transmitting session data (i.e. your database is on another server, or your memcached is running on multiple servers and you're not sure that it's using TLS to communicate between nodes), you generally don't need to do anything to the session data.
2. Auto-login is actually a complicated subject and a separate concern from normal sessions. I've previously written about [secure "remember me" cookies](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2).
3. Read the link in #2. It's not immediately clear what you're describing here, but it sounds questionable.